# scroll down to div2 using js only not jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I know this is easy in JS even in jQuery but i'm still learning would like to use Js only for some reasons. I am trying to make the window scroll down to div2 and make the top of it show first on the page, whats doing now is scroll down and make div2 in the middle of the page. this code down worked fine but now for some reason is not working! does anyone have any idea?

```js
function div2() {
      document.querySelector('.div2').scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    
    window.onload = div2();
```

```css
header {width:100%;height:150px;background:#f2f2f2;}
.div1, .div2, .div3{height:400px;width:90%;border:1px solid red;margin:0 auto;}
.div1{background: #f8f8f8;}
```

```html
<header>Main Header</header>
<div class="div1">

</div>
<div class="div2">

</div>
<div class="div3">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView the first parameter is a boolean which when true will align top like you want.

```js
function div2() {
      document.querySelector('.div2').scrollIntoView(true, { behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    
window.onload = div2();
```

```css
header {width:100%;height:150px;background:#f2f2f2;}
.div1, .div2, .div3{height:400px;width:90%;border:1px solid red;margin:0 auto;}
.div1{background: #f8f8f8;}
```

```html
<header>Main Header</header>
<div class="div1">
div1
</div>
<div class="div2">
div2
</div>
<div class="div3">
div3
</div>
```